# Align Caption Left of Vertically Centered Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the following example, is there an easy way to align the caption with the left edge of the centered image?

Currently the display looks like this:

```
      ____________________
     |                    |
     |                    |
     |                    |
     |                    |
     |____________________|
 This is my caption
```

I'd like it to look like this

```
  ____________________
 |                    |
 |                    |
 |                    |
 |                    |
 |____________________|
 This is my caption
```

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height:200px;
}

img{
  width: 400px;
  height:50px
}

.figure{
  text-align: center;
}

.caption{
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<figure class="figure">
<img src=""/>
<figcaption class="caption">
This is my caption.
</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: If you want it aligned to the left, why is `.figure` aligned to the center?

Comment: I'd like the image aligned to the center of the parent container but the caption underneath of it to be aligned to the left edge of the centered image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this.

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height:200px;
}

#imgWrap
{
  display: inline-block;
}
img{
  width: 400px;
  height:50px
}

.figure{
  text-align: center;
}

.caption{
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <figure class="figure">
        <div id='imgWrap'>
            <img src=""/>
            <figcaption class="caption">
                This is my caption.
            </figcaption>
        </div>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ***text-align*** property aligns the "figure" to the center as it is specified as 'center'.

So change it to 'left' or don't specify it at all.

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height:200px;
}

img{
  width: 400px;
  height:50px
}

.figure{
  
}

.caption{
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<figure class="figure">
<img src=""/>
<figcaption class="caption">
This is my caption.
</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'd like to keep the image center aligned.